# Phaser 3 - Fix a shape into the camera view

Tags: phaser-framework

I am trying to draw a minimap from a randomly generated matrix that represents my level.

To do so, I am drawing black or white little squares one by one to represent the matrix visually (I don't know if it the best way to do that with phaser, actually, I am a beginner with this framework).

The map draws correctly but its position is bound to the world not to camera, so when I move it is not visible anymore.

Here is the code I use to draw the map:

```
generate() {
    let wallsGraphics = this._scene.add.graphics({fillStyle : {color : LabyrinthConfig.MAPS.MINI_MAP.WALLS_COLOR}});
    let pathGraphics  = this._scene.add.graphics({fillStyle : {color : LabyrinthConfig.MAPS.MINI_MAP.PATH_COLOR}});

    // Draw the map
    let y = 0;
    for (let line of this._matrix) {
        let x = 0;
        for (let cell of line) {

            let rect    = new Phaser.Geom.Rectangle();
            rect.width  = LabyrinthConfig.MAPS.MINI_MAP.CELL_WIDTH;
            rect.height = LabyrinthConfig.MAPS.MINI_MAP.CELL_HEIGHT;
            rect.x = LabyrinthConfig.MAPS.MINI_MAP.POSITION_X + x * LabyrinthConfig.MAPS.MINI_MAP.CELL_WIDTH;
            rect.y = LabyrinthConfig.MAPS.MINI_MAP.POSITION_Y + y * LabyrinthConfig.MAPS.MINI_MAP.CELL_HEIGHT;

            cell === 0 ? wallsGraphics.fillRectShape(rect) : pathGraphics.fillRectShape(rect);

            x++;
        }
        y++;
    }
}
```

Any help on how to fix this map to the camera view ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set scroll factor of your graphics objects to 0.

```
wallsGraphics.setScrollFactor(0);
pathGraphics.setScrollFactor(0);
```